# Creating a CharAt() method in the main class

Tags: java, charat

I got stuck on this section of the code. The idea is to return the character at a given index without using **String, StringBuilder, and Wrapper classes**.

**What I have**: a "`this.data`" as a `char[]` data for my "`MyOwnString`" object.

This is my understanding on what the main class code should look like:

```
public char charAt(int index){
    create a new char from this.data,
    then use charAt() method to select a given index.
}
}
```

The string will be in a tester class. Just need some guidance on this challenging homework assignment without any of the easy shortcuts.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: charAt() is for Strings are you allowed to use charAt() if so then just do string.charAt(index) if not then convert to char array and do chararray[index].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
return data[index];
```

?

Comment: thank you very much. Guess I overlook it and thought you have to return the index as a new object. Cant believe the answer was right there. LOL

Comment: no problem. an upvote would be nice ^^
But remember, you are returning a `char`, and this isnt an object, because it is a primtive data type.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public char charAt(int index){
    return this.data[index];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i could use that also and it would still work.
I tested both data and this.data. Still work either way since it is the same data.

Comment: the this keyword is only necessary, if you have another variable in the same scope, (one scope is every `{}`, so the method in this case), which has the same name. a `this` points to the fields of a class. So here it isn't needed actually.